# How to request to Gunicorn and respond with Daphne? Using Django channels, Nginx, Gunicorn, Daphne

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-channels, daphne

I'm facing a strange issue in deploying Django app with Nginx, Daphne and Gunicorn.

As of now, I have successfully deployed my Django app.
My HTTP requests are handled by Gunicorn, and WSS requests are handled by Daphne, which is meant to happen.

Consider a scenario, where I send an HTTP request to Gunicorn, and Django needs to send a message back via channels. How do I do that?

For example, if I add a post via HTTP POST request, and want to send a notification via channels to all the open channels (which I have a list of) how do I make Django send back a channel message through Daphne, even when the request was HTTP in the first place received through Gunicorn?

The request flow that I need is:

Client  >  HTTP  >  NGINX  >  GUNICORN  >  DJANGO  >  Do some processing  >  Send notification to all open channels via WSS >  Send HTTP RESPONSE OK STATUS=200 to client

I used this guide to deploy

https://github.com/mitchtabian/HOWTO-django-channels-daphne/blob/master/README.md

Everything is working fine except I don't receive WSS messages on the client WebSocket listener, when I send a HTTP request to Gunicorn, but when I send HTTP request to Daphne I get a WSS response successfully

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a [Channel Layer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html):

> Channel layers allow you to talk between different instances of an application.

[channels_redis](https://github.com/django/channels_redis) is a good one, to transfer a message from a server to another.

The request flow will be:

```
Client request -> NGINX -> Gunicorn -> Django Application -> Send notification  -> Redis -> Websocket Consumer -> Send response
```